# Deleting parts of shapes that don't overlap in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The red and blue objects are each rectangles that have been sheared. I want to delete the parts hanging off that I've circled with the pencil tool.

I feel like I need to be using the shape builder tool for this but can't seem to figure out how to do it with that.

[image: situation]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *Shape Builder* should work fine.

1. Select both the overlapping shapes.
2. Select *Shape Builder* tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>).
3. Now, you have to remove those shapes using this tool. To remove a
   shape, you have to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> *(Alt on Windows, Option key on Mac)* key. When you hold it, it will show **-** (minus) sign, which means you're going to remove it. By default,
   it shows **+** sign.
4. Click the areas which you want to remove.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use *Divide* feature in Pathfinder panel. It will basically split it into different shapes. Once applied, it will split and group everything. You can then delete the shapes you don't need from the group.

[image]

**Note:** This method will remove overlapping effects. The overlapping parts will be gone. It will be replaced by a new common area. Basically, you'll get 3 different shapes which are adjacent to each other.